# Laravel namespace class error

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to learn how to get a role name from the role table by linking it to the user table with role_id in user table and user_id in the role table.

I'm getting this error

```
Class 'App\Role' not found (View: C:\
```

All of my Role related files all reference role and files are names, RoleController and Role.php with a view called index.blade.php.

heres my role class:

```
<?php

namespace Laravel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
//

protected $fillable = [
'name',
];

public function users()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

}
```

Its been pointed out to me its probably a namespace issue but everyting else seems to point to Laravel like RoleController has:

```
namespace Laravel\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Role;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

and user model has:

```
namespace Laravel;
```

So Why is this not working for me? as far as I can tell everything is named right.

Comment: use `namespace App;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `App` namespace is used default by Laravel, cause it use the *PSR-4 autoloading standard*.

If you want to use your   `Laravel` namespace, try to change your application name `app:name` by the artisan command like this `php artisan app:name Laravel`

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way:

**Role.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
//

protected $fillable = [
'name',
];

public function users()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

}
```

Use in `Controller` like:

```
use App\Role;
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for me, also added a pivot table.

Comment: @RathBaloth: Glad to help